# Multiple recurring profiles in one go using the NVP method return invalid token error

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to create multiple recurring profiles in one go using the NVP method with PayPal API version 112.0 ... the first profile works fine, I then call it again and I get an invalid token error. The billing agreement is all same as for the other successful profile.

Though it is clearly said in documentation that multiple profiles can be created with single payment. I am using expressCheckout. Please help on this.

Here is my code:
/*this create profile array works well*/

```
Array
(
    [METHOD] => CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile
    [TOKEN] => EC-4AW0867838N0385684F
    [INITAMT] => 180.00
    [AMT] => 180.00
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [PROFILESTARTDATE] => 2014-10-03T13:35:04Z
    [BILLINGPERIOD] => Month
    [BILLINGFREQUENCY] => 3
    [PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
    [DESC] => 1× 3 Description
    [PAYERID] => WLCZLZ2R4K7RJ
    [PROFILEREFERENCE] => 29301-1396535617
    [BUTTONSOURCE] => Ubercart_ShoppingCart_EC_US
    [NOTIFYURL] => mysite.com/uc_paypal/ipn/77301
    [ITEMAMT] => 180.00
    [SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
    [TAXAMT] => 0.00
)
```

in the next iteration it creates this array(which return **Paypal** error: **Invalid Token**)

```
Array
(
    [METHOD] => CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile
    [TOKEN] => EC-4AW0867838N0385684F
    [INITAMT] => 180.00
    [AMT] => 180.00
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [PROFILESTARTDATE] => 2015-10-03T13:35:04Z
    [BILLINGPERIOD] => Month
    [BILLINGFREQUENCY] => 13
    [PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
    [DESC] => 1× 3 Description
    [PAYERID] => WLCZLZ2R4K7RJ
    [PROFILEREFERENCE] => 29301-1396535618
    [BUTTONSOURCE] => Ubercart_ShoppingCart_EC_US
    [NOTIFYURL] => mysite.com/uc_paypal/ipn/77301
    [ITEMAMT] => 180.00
    [SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
    [TAXAMT] => 0.00
)
```

Comment: They're up to version 112.0 now.  Maybe try updating that and see if it helps.

Comment: It didn`t work by moving to this version, Can you give me any example code of multiple recurring profile creations with expressCheckout ?

Comment: I've never tried that specifically, I was just throwing that option out there to try the updated version and see if it worked.  Where is the documentation that says this is compatible?

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPRecurringPayments/

Search 'multiple recurring payments profiles' will take you directly to that part in document

Comment: I have similar problem, did you get solution to this?